# Allow users granular permission approval in React Native/iOS Facebook OAuth?

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, react-native

I'm using this package for Facebook OAuth:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-facebook-login

If I use `FBLoginManager.LoginBehaviors.SystemAccount`, when the user taps the Facebook login button, iOS will pop up a dialog asking if they want to grant access to the app. While this is convenient, the only drawback I've noticed is that I can ask for a dozen different permissions and the user has no clue what my app is requesting, nor can they selectively choose what to share.

Is there some way to give them this choice using the native iOS Facebook account? Or should I just use `FBLoginManager.LoginBehaviors.Native` which pops up an in-app browser for them to authenticate. (I was under the impression, according to the documentation, that it would switch to the Facebook app, but that doesn't happen)

Answer (score 0):

The native iOS implementation (the one built by Apple) does not support the granular permission dialog you will see when doing login through the native Facebook app or the Safari View Controller flow so your only option is to fallback to any login method that does not involve the native OS implementation.